# updating html using beautifulsoup

Tags: beautifulsoup, html-parsing, confluence

```
    with open("test.html") as fp:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, "html.parser")
        table = soup.find("table", {"class": "wrapped relative-table confluenceTable"})
        
        for row in table.findAll("tr"):
            cells = row.find(text=re.compile("CTX.*"))
            print(cells)
            cell2s = row.find(text=re.compile("ES.*"))
            cell2s.string.replace_with("ABC50")
```

Below is the Html code. Top one is table tag , then body tag comes and afterwards there are 2 tr tags. I have to update ESW2 value of both td tags.

```
 <table class="wrapped relative-table confluenceTable" style="width: <tbody> <tr>
              <td class="confluenceTd">angular/cli</td>
              <td class="confluenceTd"><a href="http://angular.io" class="external-link" rel="nofollow">angular.io</a></td>
               <td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd"><br></td>
               <td class="confluenceTd">FOSS</td>
               <td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">'11.2.14</td>
               <td class="confluenceTd">Bazaar + EVMS 22.0&#xa0;</td>
               <td class="confluenceTd"><a href="https://github.com" class="external-link" rel="nofollow">14/CTX1026329</a>&#xa0;R1A</td>
                <td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd"><br></td>
                <td class="confluenceTd">ESW2</td>
                <td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd"><br></td>
                <td class="confluenceTd"><br></td>
</tr> 
<tr>
                <td class="confluenceTd">angular/cli</td>
                <td class="confluenceTd"><a href="http://angular.io" class="external-link" rel="nofollow">angular.io</a></td>
                <td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd"><br></td>
                <td class="confluenceTd">FOSS</td>
                <td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">'11.2.14</td>
                <td class="confluenceTd">Bazaar + EVMS 22.0&#xa0;</td>
                <td class="confluenceTd"><a href="https://bazaar.internal.ericsson.com/b-view-component.php?componentid=988161" class="external-link" rel="nofollow">14/CTX1026329</a>&#xa0;R1A</td>
                <td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd"><br></td>
                <td class="confluenceTd">ESW2</td>
                <td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd"><br></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  `.find_all()` to find all the `<td>` tags that have your `"ES.*"`. Then use `.string.replace_with()`

```
with open("test.html", "r") as fp:
    html= fp.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    table = soup.find("table", {"class": "wrapped relative-table confluenceTable"})

    for each in table.find_all('td', text=re.compile("ES.*")):
        each.string.replace_with('ESW3')
```

**Output:**

```
<table class="wrapped relative-table confluenceTable" confluencetd"="" style="width: &lt;tbody&gt; &lt;tr&gt;
              &lt;td class=">angular/cli
<td class="confluenceTd"><a class="external-link" href="http://angular.io" rel="nofollow">angular.io</a></td>
<td class="confluenceTd" colspan="1"><br/></td>
<td class="confluenceTd">FOSS</td>
<td class="confluenceTd" colspan="1">'11.2.14</td>
<td class="confluenceTd">Bazaar + EVMS 22.0 </td>
<td class="confluenceTd"><a class="external-link" href="https://github.com" rel="nofollow">14/CTX1026329</a> R1A</td>
<td class="confluenceTd" colspan="1"><br/></td>
<td class="confluenceTd">ESW3</td>
<td class="confluenceTd" colspan="1"><br/></td>
<td class="confluenceTd"><br/></td>

<tr>
<td class="confluenceTd">angular/cli</td>
<td class="confluenceTd"><a class="external-link" href="http://angular.io" rel="nofollow">angular.io</a></td>
<td class="confluenceTd" colspan="1"><br/></td>
<td class="confluenceTd">FOSS</td>
<td class="confluenceTd" colspan="1">'11.2.14</td>
<td class="confluenceTd">Bazaar + EVMS 22.0 </td>
<td class="confluenceTd"><a class="external-link" href="https://bazaar.internal.ericsson.com/b-view-component.php?componentid=988161" rel="nofollow">14/CTX1026329</a> R1A</td>
<td class="confluenceTd" colspan="1"><br/></td>
<td class="confluenceTd">ESW3</td>
<td class="confluenceTd" colspan="1"><br/></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: All 3 cell statements are in scope of for loop. -->  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/PycharmProjects/Confluence_QT/tr_testing.py", line 13, in <module>
    cell2s.string.replace_with("ABC50")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string'

Comment: that means your `cell2s = row.find(text=re.compile("ES.*"))` returned `None`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes it is but it shouldn`t return none. In this Html hierarchy how can i update text "ESW2"  in side the td.

Comment: You'd do it by the method I provided above. Unless you share with me the full code/html, there's not much more I can do as to why it's returning `None`. I can only work with what you provide, and with your sample of the html here, it works.

Comment: thanks: I have edited my question and pasted full python and html code.

Comment: Are you not actually reading in the html? I made a slight adjustment. retry the code

Comment: Actually i am unable to write my html code here. unfortunately Your attest edit is also not working.  As mentioned all 3 cell statements are in for loop (Please check my question).

Comment: Ok, well in that case, just put a `if` statement. made edit above

Comment: Thanks a lot . How can make this change permanent in out html file ?

Comment: Just write it to file.

Comment: Actually i am confused how to update at a correct point, as it is a long html code and i only want to update specific position of the table in same html file

Comment: So you want to find all the cells that start with `'ES'`, and replace it with `'ESW3'`. Right?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually i want to replace all `ES` one by one  with different numbers provided by me . Like ESW3 ESW4 etc

Comment: ok, then you'll need to set up some type of "mapping" or logic. Is it always going to be +1. so ESW2 -> ESW3. and ESW3 -> ESW4?, etc